# yocto arm-poky-linux-gcc eclipse linker missing libraries

Tags: linux, yocto

For some time I try to compile and debug a simple hello word application written in C.
Unfortunately, meta-toolchain or populate_sdk generate strangle failures.

My simple application works fine(compile and debug) with the buildroot toolchain. With the installed arm-poky-linux... I get some errors.

I try to do in the same console to create env.
. /opt/poky/3.1.17/environment-setup-armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi
and run eclipse.

```
make all 
Building target: MangoPi-R3-Gpio.elf
Invoking: GNU Arm Cross C Linker
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -marm -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"MangoPi-R3-Gpio.map" -o "MangoPi-R3-Gpio.elf"  ./gpio-example.o ./gpio_lib.o   
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lc
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtendS.o: No such file or directory
/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:57: MangoPi-R3-Gpio.elf] Błąd 1
```

What did I do wrong? All of the mentioned files are in the installed folder of poky toolchain.

I created my toolchain using two options

```
bitbake console-image -c populate_sdk
```

and

```
bitbake meta-toolchain
```

the result is the same as above.

Adding
--sysroot=/opt/poky/3.1.17/sysroots/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi
also not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The game changer for me has been
running `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` with the option `--sysroot=<dir>`
where  is something like `/opt/<something>/<version>/sysroots/<arch>` and for me `<arch>` was `armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi`.

I have a Makefile and i added the option to the command in CC variable.

That was not enough, I had to perform a `make clean` before `make`, probably because I did something wrong during my trial and error.